# CNN with weights chosen by the model

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Has anyone tried the following idea: Create a convolutional neural network with weights that can be chosen by another layer of the network? For example having 5 kernels, and adding them with coefficients determined by a softmax output. This superposition could be put into a conv2d function.
Like that the network could choose which features it wants to be generated.
The input into the softmax could be the activation of another conv2d layer.
An advantage could be that one has only 1/5 of the output activations, including flops and vram (especially at the first layers).

Comment: Are you looking for [dynamic convolution](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/dynconv.pdf)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for stackoverflow. It's really open ended and not specific. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on what is on topic and what constitutes a good question.

Comment: Parag: Thank you for the link!
anothermh: ok thanks